# Disable ordering on select columns with DataTables

Tags: php, jquery, datatable, datatables

**Situation**
I am unable to disable sorting on some colums eventhough im using the 'right' code. I have seen several StackOverflow post and tried the answers. nothing seems to work and I keep getting the same error in my console.

```
SyntaxError: missing } after property list
    "aoColumnDefs": [
//or
SyntaxError: missing } after property list
    "columnDefs": [ {
```

**Code**

```
    $('#tblMarkers').DataTable({
        paging: false,
        searching: false,
        info: false
        "columnDefs": [ {
            "targets": 3,
            "orderable": false
        } ]
    });
```

EDIT: I was missing a comma... 
But another Question... how can I do multiple targets?

Comment: You are missing an comma at the end of this line: `info: false`. Could that help?

Comment: I think you are placing your code in wrong place. Could you place the code on top of docoment ready?

Comment: omg... i was actually missing that comma... Thanks!! it works now...

Comment: @MikeLammers The "targets" attribute on "columnDefs" can be an array.  So you could do "targets: [2,3,4]" on your current columnDef to disable sorting on columns 2, 3, and 4.

Answer (score 0):

Your tried

```
$('#tblMarkers').DataTable({
    paging: false,
    searching: false,
    info: false,
    "columnDefs": [ {
        "targets": 3,
        "orderable": false
    } ]
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I use something like this for this purpose;

```
 $('#tblMarkers').dataTable({
        "aaSorting": [],
        "aoColumns": [
        null,null,{ "bSortable": false }
        ]
    });
```

Null refers to default and `{ "bSortable": false }` makes the column unsortable. 
Note: This is a 3 column table with last column unsortable.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple targets are simply an array of indexes. This works for me:

[source doc](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columnDefs)

```
$('#data_table').DataTable({
    "columnDefs": [
        { "orderable": false, "targets": [0, 4, 5, 6] },
        { "orderable": true, "targets": [1, 2, 3] }
    ]
});
```